# Summarize a calculated measure using average instead of SUM

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following DAX that give the utilization of my team. It works well when slicing by individuals but when I try to do a grouping of them it adds up all of the percentages instead of averaging them. Is there a way to force DAX to average them instead of sum them? The `TIMESHEETS` table has the hours booked by my team and there are multiple rows per day and per person.

```
Utilization = 
CALCULATE (
    DIVIDE (
        SUM ( TIMESHEETS[Hours] ),
         (
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( TIMESHEETS[Actual Date] ),
                'Calendar (Actual Date)'[Weekday/Weekend] = "Weekday"
            ) * 7.5
        )
    ),
    'Calendar (Actual Date)'[Weekday/Weekend] = "Weekday",
    'CHARGE CODES'[Billable/Non-Billable] = "Billable"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating 3 different measures

```
TimeSheetHours:=calculate(sum(timesheets[Hours]),
    'Calendar (Actual Date)'[Weekday/Weekend] = "Weekday",
    'CHARGE CODES'[Billable/Non-Billable] = "Billable")

EmployeeHours:=CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( TIMESHEETS[Actual Date] ),
                'Calendar (Actual Date)'[Weekday/Weekend] = "Weekday"
            ) * 7.5

Utilization:=[TimeSheetHours]/[EmployeeHours]
```